# Как поменять местами элементы в массиве с помощью деструктуризации?

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть массив объектов, каким образом я могу поменять местами определенные элементы?

```
const arr = [
  {value: 1},
  {value: 2},
  {value: 3},
  {value: 4},
  {value: 5},
  {value: 6},
]
```

Как сделать что бы 0 и 1 , 2 и 3, 4 и 5 поменялись местами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный подход для обмена значений двух переменных - использование временной переменной:

```
var tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

Также можно воспользоваться деструктурирующим присваиванием

```
[a,b] = [b,a]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать что бы 0 и 1 , 2 и 3, 4 и 5 поменялись местами?

Что вам мешает сделать это в лоб?

```
for (i = 1; i < arr.len; i += 2) {
    const tmp = arr[i - 1];
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = tmp;
}
```

или так

Comment: Потому что у меня намного больше массив на деле, и элементы стоят хаотично, к примеру нужно поменять 1 и 5 элемент, 2 и 8 и тд И мне не нужно весь массив изменять

Comment: @stack overflow, тогда пожалуйста переформулируйте вопрос, так чтоб была понятна суть ЧТО ИМЕННО вам требуется

Comment: Как я могу поменять местами определенные элементы в массиве?  к примеру нужно поменять 1 и 5 элемент, 2 и 8 , 5 и 17 и тд Мне подсказали что можно с помощью деструктуризации, но я пока не знаю как это сделать

Comment: `tmp = arr[5]; arr[5]=arr[17]; arr[17]=tmp` - так не устраивает?

Comment: Ничего не происходит когда так делаю

Comment: @stackoverflow, очевидно ты делаешь не так ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: 0 и 1 хочу поменять

        changedSettings = changedSettings[0] 
        changedSettings[0] = changedSettings[1] 
        changedSettings[1] = changedSettings

Comment: @stackoverflow, ну вот, ошибка очевидна. ты переписываешь саму переменную `changedSettings` - если бы выбрал любое другое название для временной переменной, как в примерах в ответах - все бы работало